# How do I model my document in MongoDB to make it paginable for nested attributes?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, database-design, twitter, pagination

I'm trying to cache my tweets and show that based on my keyword save. However, as tweets grow overtime I need to paginate them.

I'm using Ruby and Mongoid which this is what I have come up so far.

```
class SavedTweet
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :saved_id,            :type => String
    field :slug,                :type => String
    field :tweets,              :type => Array
end
```

And the `tweets` array would be like this

```
{id: "id", text: "text", created_at: "created_at"}
```

So it's like a bucket for each keyword that you can save. My first problem would be that Mongodb cannot sort the second level of document which in this case it's `tweets` and that'd make pagination much harder because I cannot use skip and limit. I will have to load the whole tweets and put that in the cache and paginate from that.

The question is how should I model my problem to make it paginable out of Mongodb and not in the memory. I'm assuming that doing it in Mongodb would be faster. Right now, I'm in the early stage of my application so it's easier to change the model than later. If you guys have any suggestions or opinion I'm really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option could be to save tweets in a different collection and link them with your SavedTweet class. It will be easy to query and you could use skip and limit without problems.

```
{id: "id", text: "text", created_at: "created_at", saved_tweet:"_id"}
```

**EDIT: a better explanation, with two aditional options**

As far I see, you have three options, if I understand correctly your requirements:

**Use the same schema that you are already using.** You would have two problems: you cannot use skip and limit with an usual query and you have a limit of 16 MB per document. I think, the first one could be resolved with an **Aggregation Framework** query ($unwind, $skip and $limit could be helpful). The second one could be a problem if you have a lot of tweet documents in the array, because one document cannot have more than 16MB of size.

**Use two collections to store your tweets**. One collection would have the same structure that you already have. For example:

```
{
 save_id:"23232",
 slug:"adkj"
}
```

And the other collection would have one document per tweet.

```
{
id: "id", 
text: "text", 
created_at: "created_at", 
saved_tweet:"_id"
}
```

With saved_tweet field you are linking **saved_tweets** with **tweet** with a 1 to N relation. So with this way, you can carry out queries over tweet collection and still be able to use limit and skip operators..

**Save all info in the  same document.** If your **saved_tweet** collection only have those fields, you can save all info in a whole document (one document for each tweet). Something like this:

```
{
  save_id:"23232",
  slug:"adkj"
  tweet: 
   {
    tweet_id: "id", 
    text: "text", 
    created_at: "created_at"
   }
}
```

Whit this solution you are duplicating fields, because *save_id* and *slug would* be the same in other documents of the same **saved_tweet**, but I could be an option if you have  a little quantity of fields and that fields are not subdocuments or arrays.

I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it. Would that mean I could just have one collection (saved_tweets) but flatten the tweets to be documents. Could you please give me an example?